# Is it important to use CSRF in the inner pages of admin?

Tags: php, mysql, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using some functions for having csrf protection in my php codes ,

But i have a question.

I have already used them in login form of admin area, is it important to have them in the forms of admin area?

I have so many forms in admin area to do admin works but they don't have csrf token generator.

And my question is that , Is it needed to generate csrf tokens in the inner pages of admin area ?

Comment: CSRF is more important for the admin part than for the login. Do you understand what CSRF protection tries to prevent?

Comment: @PeeHaa yes but not compeletly, it preveents sending requests to admin area by another server like loading a function of admin in frame or any other thing, I have it in login but , is the hacker able to do a attack for inner page? I think he can do it :-?

Comment: Go read up on the topic here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is more important to use them for the inner pages that it is for the login page.

A CSRF attack against your login page could result in a user being logged in as someone they don't expect to be logged in as.

A CSRF attack against your (for example) delete user page, could result in a user (who is an admin) deleting people's accounts when they don't expect to.

Comment: a question: Is it important to generate a New One token for every and every form and submit ? Or One enough for all site ?

Comment: @Pafo — If you have a new question, then ask a new question, don't make a comment. That one is will elicit rather opinionated answers though.